# Is it possible in Quickbooks Desktop to do an IIF transaction import which keys off of a customer id rather than the 'NAME' field?

Tags: import, quickbooks, invoice

First of all, yes, I know that IIF (Intuit Interchange Format) files are a deprecated way of transferring data into Quickbooks Desktop.

However, I have been tasked with writing a PHP script that will create an IIF file that a customer could use to import an invoice that is created by my web application. If it were my choice, I wouldn't attempt to use IIF.

**The Question:**
Using an IIF import, is it possible to have Quickbooks use either its internal ids, an account number (which ends up in the `NOTE` field), or a custom field to link the customer to the invoice rather than using the `NAME` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is no.

The closest thing I could find to an answer was from here:
https://community.intuit.com/questions/1575622-how-do-you-import-iif-file-using-a-custom-field-as-identifier

The answer from that link:

> "Custom Fields are not a Key Field; Vendor Name is the Key Field. You
>   cannot import Bills except by reference to the Relational key field of
>   Vendor Name. This is a relational database, so the things that matter
>   are the Key Fields. AP and Vendor Name, at a minimum, define Bills."

My question was about transactions rather than Bills, but I imagine that the same answer that applies to Bills applies to Invoices and the customer `Name`.